# Python interpreter hangs - experimenting with thread and queues

Tags: python-2.7, python-multithreading

Following successfully hangs on exit

```
import threading
import Queue as queue 
import time
import sys

class WorkItem(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self.P1 = 20
        self.P2 = 40

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print "P1 = %d" % (self.P1)
        print "P2 = %d" % (self.P2)

class WorkQueue(object):
    def __init__(self,queueLimit = 5):

        self.WorkQueue = queue.Queue(queueLimit)
        self.dispatcherThread = threading.Thread(target=self.DequeueWorker)
        self.dispatcherThread.start()
        self.QueueStopEvent = threading.Event()
        self.QueueStopEvent.clear()

    def DequeueWorker(self):
        print "DequeueWorker Enter .."
        while not self.QueueStopEvent.isSet():
            workItem = self.WorkQueue.get(True)
            workItem.start()

    def DispatchToQueue(self,workItem):

        self.WorkQueue.put(workItem,True)

    def Stop(self):
        self.QueueStopEvent.set()
        self.queue = None 


def main():
    q = WorkQueue()
    for i in range(1,20):
        t  = WorkItem()
        q.DispatchToQueue(t)

    time.sleep(10)
    q.Stop()



if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I can see the DequeueWorker is the one still running and pending and trying to understand why since I do signal the Stop event. I was expecting the loop would exit.

```
>>> $w
=> Frame id=0, function=DequeueWorker
   Frame id=1, function=run
   Frame id=2, function=__bootstrap_inner
   Frame id=3, function=__bootstrap
```

Help appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `get` with `block` set to `True`, which means it will block until an item is actually available in the queue.  In your code, once the work queue is exhausted, the next `get` will indefinitely block since it is waiting for an additional work item that will never come (and not letting the next iteration of the `while` loop execute, so the status of `QueueStopEvent` doesn't get checked anymore).  Try modifying your `DequeueWorker` method to this:

```
def DequeueWorker(self):
    print "DequeueWorker Enter .."
    while not self.QueueStopEvent.isSet():
        try:
          workItem = self.WorkQueue.get(True, timeout=3)
          workItem.start()
        except queue.Empty: continue
```

Now when `get` is called after the work queue is exhausted, it will timeout (after 3 seconds in this case, I chose that arbitrarily) and raise the `queue.Empty` exception.  In this case, we're simply going to let the loop continue to the next iteration where the loop will break itself when `QueueStopEvent` eventually gets set.

Other options would be to invoke `get` with `block` set to `False` or to use the `get_nowait` method inside that `try`/`except` block:

```
workItem = self.WorkQueue.get(False)
workItem = self.WorkQueue.get_nowait()
```

Although that creates a very tight `while` loop when the queue is empty.

Comment: Shouldn't the top of the stack call be get in this case since I can  only see  Frame id=0, function=DequeueWorker as the first frame while debugging

Comment: @Addy I can't speak to the particular debugging solution you are using, but I know that if I insert `print` statements before and after that `get` call it clearly illustrates that after the queue is exhausted `get` never returns (and the second `print` statement doesn't execute).

Comment: Thats a visual studio python tools , its the same pdb as well